# Why do wet get the "Can't vectorise expression GHC.Prim.Int#" error in DPH programs?

Tags: haskell, data-parallel-haskell

I was trying to implement the nqueens problem using DPH but I ended up with the Can't vectorise GHC.Prim.Int# error. When I googled for the error I found a GHC Bug which talks about vectorizing literals used for pattern matching (http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/GHC-5702-Can-t-vectorise-pattern-matching-on-numeric-literals-td5076659.html). I am not sure if this is the same bug. 
My code is as follows,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelArrays #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fvectorise #-}
module NQueensP (nqueens_wrapper) 
where

import qualified Prelude
import Data.Array.Parallel
import Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude
import Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude.Int as I
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel.PArray as P


isSafe i q n  = isSafeHelper i (Prelude.zip (P.toList (toPArrayP q)) [n, n I.- 1..1]) 
            where isSafeHelper i []  = True
                  isSafeHelper i (x:xs) = (i I.== Prelude.fst x) && I.abs(i I.-   
                                  (Prelude.fst x)) I./= I.abs(n I.- (Prelude.snd x)) && 
                                       isSafeHelper i xs

nqueens_wrapper::Int -> PArray (PArray Int)
nqueens_wrapper n = toPArrayP (mapP toPArrayP (nqueens n 0))

nqueens::Int -> Int -> [:[:Int:]:]
nqueens n 1 = [:[:i:] | i <- (enumFromToP 1 n) :]
nqueens n k = [: [:i:] +:+ q | i <- oneton, q <- boards, isSafe i q k:]
           where boards = nqueens n (k I.- 1)
                 oneton = (enumFromToP 1 n)
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. I am using GHC 7.4.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be related to the bug you referred to. The error you get stems from this line:

```
nqueens n 1 = [:[:i:] | i <- (enumFromToP 1 n) :]
```

Apparently, you can't use n-patterns with `-fvectorise` enabled. Let's manually desugar this line to remove the n-pattern:

```
nqueens n w | w I.== 1 = [:[:i:] | i <- (enumFromToP 1 n) :]
```

---

We have now dealt with one cryptic error message. This doesn't mean that we're done, because the next error message seems just as cryptic:

```
*** Vectorisation error ***
    Tycon not vectorised:  []
```

The problem with `isSafe` (I think) is that you're using a lot of data types and variables that weren't compiled with `-fvectorise`. This means you can't just use linked lists (`Tycon not vectorised:  []`), `Prelude.fst`, `Prelude.snd`, or `Prelude.zip`, unless you redefine those structures in your module. (Annoyingly enough, I can't even use `(.)` without redefining it.)

We will have to rewrite `isSafe`. Let's look at the first line of it:

```
isSafe i q n  = isSafeHelper i (Prelude.zip (P.toList (toPArrayP q)) [n, n I.- 1..1])
```

We can't use `Prelude.zip`, but we could use `zipP` instead, which means we don't have to convert `q` anymore. However, our decreasing list should be rewritten using DPH combinators. Stupidly enough, `enumFromThenToP` doesn't exist, so instead, we'll say `mapP (n I.-) (enumFromToP 0 (n I.- 1))` to get the parallel equivalent of `[n, n I.- 1..1]`. So this line becomes:

```
isSafe i q n  = isSafeHelper i (zipP q (mapP (n I.-) (enumFromToP 0 (n I.- 1))))
```

Now for `isSafeHelper`:

```
isSafeHelper i [] = True
isSafeHelper i (x:xs)
    = (i I.== Prelude.fst x)
    && I.abs(i I.- (Prelude.fst x)) I./= I.abs(n I.- (Prelude.snd x))
    && isSafeHelper i xs
```

Because `Prelude.fst` and `Prelude.snd` are unavailable, you can fix this by just extracting these parts of the tuple in the pattern itself:

```
isSafeHelper i [] = True
isSafeHelper i ((x1,x2):xs)
    = (i I.== x1)
    && I.abs(i I.- x) I./= I.abs(n I.- x2)
    && isSafeHelper i xs
```

But, of course, it still won't compile: your argument will be a parallel list, not a Prelude-style linked list. To deal with this, we're going to rewrite this in a more functional style, using the function [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
isSafeHelper i xs = all (isSafePredicate i) xs

isSafePredicate i (x1,x2)
    = (i I.== x1)
    && I.abs(i I.- x) I./= I.abs(n I.- x2)
```

`all` still works on linked lists, but note that you're not manually deconstructing the list in your own function. Wouldn't it be nice if there were an `allP` for parallel lists? It would, but there isn't. It's not hard to write it, though:

```
allP :: (a -> Bool) -> [: a :] -> Bool
allP p arr = andP (mapP p arr)
```

Putting it all together, you can write `isSafe` as follows:

```
isSafe i q n = allP (isSafePredicate i n) (zipP q ntoone) 
  where
    isSafePredicate i n (x1, x2)
        = (i I.== x1)
        && I.abs(i I.- x1) I./= I.abs(n I.- x2)
    ntoone = mapP (n I.-) (enumFromToP 0 (n I.- 1))
```

---

`nqueens_wrapper` seems fine as it is. Your code should now compile.

A few notes:

- I don't know whether it works (I get `*** Exception: crossMapP: not implemented`, and don't know how to fix it), but it looks like it should.
- Rewriting `isSafe` the other way around won't work. If you try to work with `Prelude` numbers in `Prelude` lists, you'll end up with the complaint about `Int#` again. I think this is because `isSafe` is used by at least one vectorised function `nqueens`.
- Don't include `Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude`. The [module description](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dph-lifted-vseg/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Parallel-Prelude.html) says so:

  > *This module should not be explicitly imported in user code anymore.* User code should only import Parallel and, until the vectoriser supports type classes, the type-specific modules.
- Don't go crazy with local definitions. `isSafeHelper` is missing its `n` argument in your version.